# Apache: How to make the same rewrite rule without using THE_REQUEST?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

How to make the same rewrite rule without using `THE_REQUEST`?

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite multiple slashes with single slash after domain
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

**Update:**
.htaccess location - www.domain.com/url/.htaceess
Rewrite action - www.domain.com//url/id rewrited to www.domain.com/url/id

Comment: I guess `THE_REQUEST` is the only one variable, that contains multiple preceding slashes. So the answer: No.

Comment: Don't forget about `?`queries – you probably don't want to remove slashes from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are no solution without Apache `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
>   ^(.*)//(.*)$ RewriteRule . %1/%2
>   [R=301,L]

Taken [from here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/07/21/redirect-or-rewrite-to-remove-double-or-multiple-slashes-in-url/). (Unfortunately I'm unable to test it here).

Comment: Your rewrite rule will not work when .htaccess will be in localhost/dir/.htaccess (localhost//dir/ will be returned the same).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't match multiple slashes at the beginning of the URL like in `http://domain.com///file.htm`, because these slashes aren't contained in `%{REQUEST_URI}`...

Comment: @Floern - You can check, my rule works fine, just I was wondering to make the same thing with `REQUEST_URI` and not `THE_REQUEST`.

Comment: I'm curious - why don't you want to use THE_REQUEST if it does what you need?

Comment: @DanTup - Danny Tuppeny - `THE_REQUEST` returns urlencode for non Latin urls, but I need to return urldecode.

Comment: Right, got you. Sadly I don't have another answer :(